# using jmeter to upload an app to cloud foundry end point /v2/apps/${appguid}/bits

Tags: jmeter, cloud-foundry

Has anyone successfully used Jmeter to upload an app to the Cloud Foundry endpoint /v2/apps/${appguid}/bits ? If so, please would you be so kind as to share the configuration that you used. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While not a Jmeter config, there's a technical break down of what the request needs to do here -> http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/251/apps/uploads_the_bits_for_an_app.html  You should be able to use that to build out the request in JMeter.  You could also setup Jmeter as a proxy and have it record traffic.  If you set the CF cli to use the proxy, you could then issue a `cf push` and record the interaction.  It's more than just the upload request, but it should include that as well.

Comment: Thank you for responding Daniel. I had already spent some considerable time tinkering with the detail provided by the cf documentation without success before penning my question. I had also tried using the Jmeter proxy to record the comms between the cf cli push and the cf endpoint again without a successful conclusion. cf push not using the Jmeter proxy is successful. I was also unable to find anything on the web regarding this specific subject. That is why I was after confirmation from someone that had successfully used jmeter for the operation.

Comment: Jmeter in this case is just a HTTP client.  Assuming you can find the right configuration for said client, you can make this work.  I don't know what that would be as it's not something I've had the occasion to do.  Perhaps someone else will come along who has and be able to answer your question. What you might consider doing is posting more details about what you've done to this point and what specifically hasn't worked.  Perhaps someone will be able to spot what's not working right and help you come up  with a working configuration.